# Two different random generated numbers in Swift

Tags: swift, random, label

I want that my two random generated labels does not generate the same number like 5 and 5

I have done everything else but this

```
else if rightScoreLabel == leftScoreLabel {
// what goes here?
{
```

sorry i’m starter

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try approaching this another way: keep generating new numbers until you have two different values.

```
var a = 0
var b = 0
while a == b {
    a = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
    b = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
}
```

Alternatively, you can regenerate just one of the numbers:

```
var a = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
var b = 0
repeat {
    b = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
} while a == b
```

Comment: Why generate `a` more than once?

Comment: @maddy I just thought that might be more intuitive. I will edit the answer.

Comment: why generate `b` if you're just going to keep going until it matches `a` - surely this is an algorithm for generating ONE random number?

Comment: @Russell The 2nd set of code only repeats while the two are the same. Once `b` is different, the loop stops.

Comment: d'oh.  i read the description, not the code!  'until they are equal' should be 'while they are equal'!